# How to use Delete all functionality in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to delete records from EF by using this query:

```
 public void ClearAllLocks(Lock LockObj)
    {
        var Stf = context.Locks.First(S => S.UserId == LockObj.UserId);

        if (Stf == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        context.Locks.DeleteObject(Stf);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But I am only able to delete the first record and I know the reason as well (as I am using First), what should I write instead of First so that all the entries can be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void ClearAllLocks(Lock LockObj)
{
    var locksToDelete = context.Locks.Where(s => s.UserId == LockObj.UserId);

    foreach(var stf in locksToDelete)
       context.Locks.DeleteObject(stf);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Also you can use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) (search at NuGet):

```
public void ClearAllLocks(Lock LockObj)
{
    context.Locks.Delete(s => s.UserId == LockObj.UserId);        
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yes I did the same and when I checked the second solution was the one which I have executed.